# Confidence interval for categorical data

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, hypothesis-testing, confidence-interval, multinomial-distribution

I have the following data:

```
       ND  NI  SC  PI  PA
Green  27   3   9   4   7
Blue   24  14  14   6   8
```

I want to do the following:

1. Write the multinomial model for the data and the hypothesis for the two possible categorizations.
2. Do an appropriate test for independence between the two possible categorizations?
3. Make a 95% independence interval for the **ratio** of colors in the PA-category.

**My approach**:

**1.**

I create the following models:

$$
M_0:\quad \{X_{ij}\} \sim \mathrm{Multinom}(116,\{\pi_{ij}\}) \\
\pi_{ij} \ge 0, \sum_{ij}\pi_{ij}=1
$$

$$
M_1:\quad \{X_{ij}\} \sim \mathrm{Multinom}(116,\{\pi_{ij}\}) \\
\pi_{ij}=\alpha_i\beta_j \\
\alpha_i \ge 0, \sum_{i}\alpha_i=1, \quad \beta_j \ge 0, \sum_j \beta_j=1 \\
$$

I formulate the hypothesis as the following:

$$
H_0: \quad \pi_{ij}=\alpha_i \text{ for alle } i=1,2 \text{ and } j=1,2,\dots ,5
$$

**2.**

I do this test in R. Since I get an expected value below 5, I use Fisher's test instead of the G test:

```
mat=rbind(c(27,3,9,4,7),c(24,14,14,6,8))
fisher.test(mat)

Output:
p-value = 0.1377
```

So I cannot reject the hypothesis that the two categories are independent.

**3.**

Here I have a hunch that I should find the confidence interval for a binomial distribution, but I'm stuck. I would like to calculate this in R too. I would appreciate help.